# Mobile Accessibility : Focus moves to address bar on radio button, checkbox and button click on IOS 12.1.4 + voice over

Tags: iphone, accessibility, mobile-safari, voiceover, ios12

After updating IOS version to 12.1.4, focus moves to address bar on radio button click.It's working fine on OS V-12.0.1.

**Steps:** 
go to https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Enable the voice over.select male radio button then move focus to female radio button and select female radio button.Focus moves to address bar after selecting female radio button.

Focus moves to address bar when second radio button gets selected.

same behavior can be observed on https://www.accessibilityoz.com/forms/mobile-app-accessibility-audit-request/.

same behavior observed with checkbox and button click event.

I tried to fix it by keeping focus on radio button on click event using javascript but after 1 second focus moves back to address bar.

This is working fine on windows + NVDA ,mac + VO, android + talkback.

Comment: Ack! Don't work around the issue, report it to apple. I get the same problem in iOS 12.1.1. The behavior on the w3schools page is a little different if I run in portrait or landscape.  In portrait, the focus goes to the address bar but in landscape, it goes to the "back" button. Either way, it's bad. Also in portrait, swiping right only goes to the circle-button of the radios whereas in landscape, swiping right goes to the circle-button and then to the label text, as separate "tab stops".

Comment: you should also check https://www.applevis.com. it's not an official apple site but is good with keeping up with voiceover changes. i didn't see anything in https://www.applevis.com/bugs or https://www.applevis.com/blog. you could search https://www.applevis.com/forum or post the question there.

Comment: Thanks for entering a bug. No one outside of Apple will be able to see this bug report except you. It’s linked to your Apple ID. Apple doesn’t have a public interface to their buglist. While it’s noble to look for a workaround, the hack could potentially break other screen readers or keyboard interaction. It’s best to leave it up to Apple to fix.

Comment: bug present in iOS 12.2 as well

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue of VO jumping to either the address bar or to the "Reader" button on most websites in Safari. I am running iOS 12.1.4 on a new iPhone XR. I took my iPhone to the Apple Store and they couldn't figure it out wither, so they replaced my iPhone with a new one, but the issue persists! This doesn't happen in Google Chrome on my iPhone, so my temporary workaround is to use the GMail app instead of Apple Mail. This way, when I click on a link within an email message, it opens in Google Chrome instead of Safari. I am reporting this bug to Apple Accessibility.